# PHP PDO broken because of mysql init_connect

Tags: php, mysql

I have a small PDO script that asks the server for information in a tabel. I tought loggin the connections was a good idea and added:

```
SET GLOBAL init_connect = "INSERT INTO admin.connections (connect_time, user, connection_id) VALUES (NOW(), CURRENT_USER(), CONNECTION_ID());";
```

All the permissions should be good on mysql, tough when i execute that command the webpage returns a 500 error, if i remove it everything works perfectly.

Comment: Please add the PHP you are using. If the issue is present outside of PHP then PHP is irrelevant.

Comment: try to read your log files